# Spy an object with Moq (C#)

Tags: c#, moq, spy

I am building a .NET Core application and  I want to spy on an instantiated object using Moq, but I have not found a way to do it.

Basically, what I need is what is described [here](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy) as spying.

I have found that I can call the base class methods of a class `Foo` using the following way:

```
 var mock = new Mock<Foo>();
 mock.CallBase = true;
```

My problem is that Moq will create a new instance of Foo while what I need is to use an already instantiated object and mock only one method of the real object while calling the real functions of the object.

Here is the structure of the object I want to spy on.

```
    public class Foo:Boo
    {
       Foo(Propeties props):base(props){}

       public Baz MockMe(){...}

       public Daz DoNotMockMe(){ 
           return DoSomethingWith(Properties);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moq does not support existing objects. However, it does accept parameters to invoke constructors. This might be the solution when we use a workaround like the decorator pattern.

Do note there is a caveat when using (existing) instances: Classes using your mocked instance (`carMock.Object`) use your configured setups. However, the class under test itself (`actualCar`) is unaware it is being decorated and therefore does *not* as shown in the example below.

```
public class Car : ICar
{
    public virtual string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public virtual string Model { get; set;}
    public virtual string Name => $"{Manufacturer} {Model}";
}

public class CarTestHelper : ICar
{
    private readonly ICar _innerCar;

    public CarTestHelper(ICar car)
    {
        _innerCar = car;
    }

    // These properties use the existing instance passed in the constructor
    public string Manufacturer { get => _innerCar.Manufacturer; set => _innerCar.Manufacturer = value; }
    public virtual string Model { get => _innerCar.Model; set => _innerCar.Model = value; } // Virtual property can be mocked using Moq
    public string Name => _innerCar.Name; // Does NOT use mocked 'Model'.
}    

[TestFixture]
public class CarTests
{
    [Test]
    public void NameIsManufacturerWithModel()
    {
        var actualCar = new Car
        {
            Manufacturer = "Nissan",
            Model = "100NX"
        };

        var carMock = new Mock<CarTestHelper>(actualCar)  // Pass the decorated car as constructor parameter
        {
            CallBase = true
        };

        carMock.SetupGet(c => c.Model).Returns("200SX");

        Assert.AreEqual("Nissan 200SX", carMock.Object.Name);  // Will fail as the car will not used the mocked value.
    }
}
```

Visual studio has a nice quick fix to implement the decorator pattern automatically when you inherit from `ICar` and have it as a constructor parameter.